# Howto configure openSuSE firewall to route local traffic to local ports

Tags: firewall, redirect, port-forwarding, opensuse

I have openSUSE 11.3 installed. I'm using the openSUSE firewall configuration mechanism (`/etc/sysconfig/SuSEfirewall2`). I have a http server application running on port 8080. I want the http service to be accessible using port 80. I created a redirect rule usign:

```
FW_REDIRECT="0/0,0/0,tcp,80,8080"
```

This works fine for every request coming from external. But it doesn't for local requests. (example: `wget http://myserver/`)

Is there a way how I can tell the firewall to redirect local requests addressed for 80 to port 8080? (using the SUSE firewall configuration file)

Comment: change the http server to listen on 80? =)

Comment: Running a process which listens on 80 requires root privileges. I avoid running processes as root if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of. The openSUSE firewall doesn't get invoked when coming from 'inside' as it were.

Comment: The firewall will be `iptables` based though and it's definitely capable of applying rules 'inside'. If you can't configure it via SuSefirewall then you could add them manually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a SuSe user so I can't speak for it's firewall config, going by sysadmin1138's answer I assume SuSe might be specifying an interface for the redirect you are adding or only adding the redirect to the `FORWARD` NAT table which local traffic does not traverse.

To see what SuSe has configured:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -vnL
```

To apply the redirect for local traffic from any interface with `iptables`:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT --protocol tcp --destination YO.UR.IP.AD --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

You would then need to persist this with your [SuSe firewall setup](http://blog.vectorcomputing.net/2012/05/10/enabling-custom-firewall-rules-on-suse-11-x/) or figure out the equivalent SuSe config.